# VBS Permission Error

Tags: vbscript

```
Dim strFile2 = User & "\Documents"
Dim objFSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim Documents = objFSO2.GetFolder(strFile2)
Documents = CDec(Documents.Size / bytesToGb)
MsgBox(Documents)
```

Error:

[image: Screenshot]

```
System.Security.SecurityException occurred HResult=-2146828218
  Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0046 (CTL_E_PERMISSIONDENIED)
  Source="" StackTrace: 
    at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.LateGet(O‌​bject o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack)
    at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGe‌​t(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)         
    at ExportImport.Form1.Export_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
 in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Export Import\ExportImport\ExportImport\Form1.vb:line 42 
InnerException:
```

This statement is giving the error:

```
Documents = CDec(Documents.Size / bytesToGb)
```

I was curious if there is a way around this error or a way to fix it.

Comment: The image isn't horrible, but please copy/paste the text of the error so we don't have to click through to read it.

Comment: VBScript doesn't have a function `CDec()`, and the error message is not a VBScript error. Is this VB.net? Also, where does `bytesToGb` come from (and `User` for that matter)? You don't define the variables anywhere in your code.